# Lebesgue differentiation theorem extended for surface integrals

Tags: integration, lebesgue-measure, surface-integrals, online-resources

Theorem 6, pg 649 in appendix E of evans states the Lebesgue differentiation theorem:

> THEOREM 6 (Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem). Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be locally summable. Then for a.e. point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
> $$
> \frac{1}{|B\left(x_0, r\right)|}\int_{B\left(x_0, r\right)} f d x \rightarrow f\left(x_0\right) \quad \text { as } r \rightarrow 0 .
> $$

I would like to know if its possible to extend it for a surface integral, that is,
$$
\frac{1}{|\partial B\left(x_0, r\right)|}\int_{\partial B\left(x_0, r\right)} f(x) dS_x \rightarrow f\left(x_0\right) \quad \text { as } r \rightarrow 0 .
$$
where $|\partial B\left(x_0, r\right)|$ denotes the surface area of the ball $B\left(x_0, r\right)$. This seems very intuitive, but I couldn't find any sources online. Please note that $f$ is not necessarily continuous.

Edit :  Assume $f \in H^{1}(\overline{\Omega})$, where $\Omega = B\left(x_0, r\right)$.

Comment: Restriction to a surface doesn't even make sense for a general locally integrable function since surfaces have measure 0. You need some kind of Sobolev space smoothness for there to be a well defined restriction to a surface.

Comment: @Mason are you suggesting that the expression I wrote doesn't make sense ? I have seen this expression in evans, page 26, but they have used continuity arguments to prove the above mentioned result.

Comment: It makes sense for $f \in H^1$ at least.

Comment: @Mason alright, we can go with that. I will edit the problem! How do we proceed when $f \in H^1$?

Comment: It is an interesting question. Maybe you could prove a maximal inequality with respect to, say, the $H^1$ norm. The maximal inequality approach is what proved the Lebesgue Differentiation theorem.